# Block Cipher output length puzzle

Tags: cryptography, block, encryption

My questions is - how the length of output ciphertext be determined?

I vaguely know that the output length must be a multiple of block size of the cipher being used. But does that mean:

1. If the length of input data is a multiple of cipher block size, then the output length will be the same as the input length?
2. If the length of input data is not a multiple of cipher block size, then the output length will be the input length + one block size?

Thanks!

Comment: better fit for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Robert is correct regarding the ciphertext size depending on the cipher mode and the padding, and possibly the block mode.

If you use a cipher in streaming mode (e.g. CTR) then the ciphertext size is identical to the plaintext size. If you use an authenticated mode such as GCM then you would have to increase this with at least the authentication tag. You can also use CBC mode with cipher text stealing to (CTS) to get rid of the padding overhead, but that only works for two blocks or more.

Now lets assume PKCS#5/7 compliant padding for CBC mode, the most commonly used mode at this time. In this case your plaintext is padded with at least a single padding byte (otherwise the unpadding cannot distinguish between e.g. plaintext padded with a single `01` valued padding byte and a plaintext - dividable by the block size - ending with a `01` valued byte). This means that if the plaintext is already block aligned that an entire block is added.

Of course, if the plaintext is not block aligned then the PKCS#7 padding only needs to fill the last block. So in that case 1 to `block size` bytes are added. So the calculation becomes:

L<sub>ciphertext</sub> = (L<sub>plaintext</sub> / L<sub>block</sub>) * (L<sub>block</sub> + 1)

Where L<sub>plaintext</sub> / L<sub>block</sub> is rounded down (as usual when doing integer calculations in most programming languages).

Now lets assume AES, which always has a block size of 16 bytes:

```
  0 bytes -> 16 bytes
  1 byte  -> 16 bytes
  2 bytes -> 16 bytes
 ...
 15 bytes -> 16 bytes
 16 bytes -> 32 bytes
 17 bytes -> 32 bytes
 ...
```

Note that there are quite some implementations that use non-standardized padding. An example is the mcrypt library in PHP (you can probably use mcrypt as a base for any bad practice in cryptography). This uses zero padding, thus it simply pads `00` valued bytes until the plaintext is block aligned. In that case the resulting size can be calculated like this:

L<sub>ciphertext</sub> = (L<sub>plaintext</sub> / L<sub>block</sub> - 1) * (L<sub>block</sub> + 1)

Obviously you run into trouble when you use this with any implementation not expecting the non-standardized zero padding, or when the plaintext may end with one or more `00` valued bytes.

Final note: some languages (e.g. Java `Cipher`) have methods to retrieve the block size and even the resulting ciphertext from the encryption implementation. It never hurts to check the API before you start implementing things yourself.

Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation about the [padding modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the output ciphertext depends on the block length, on the cipher mode and if a padding is used.

There are cipher modes like CTS that create an cipher output length equal to the input, even with block ciphers.

Regarding 1:
If the length of input data is a multiple of cipher block size and padding is used, then the output length will be one block larger because you need at least one byte to specify the padding length.

Regarding 2: The output length must be a multiple of the block length, therefore it is input length + (input-length *mod* block-length)

Comment: No, #2 is not correct. The output length will be aligned with the next block boundary. Just adding a block size to the plaintext size (which is often done to quickly calculate buffer size) will result in a number that is too high.

Comment: @owlstead You are totally right, I corrected my answer.